# Text selection adds extra spaces in Sumatra PDF

Tags: pdf, font-encodings, sumatrapdf, lmodern

The following document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

result in the following weird selection behavior in Sumatra PDF v3.2:

[image]

(the d is selected, but the bounding box is wrong)

Which when copied gives the text `He l l o w or l d`.

If I remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, everything seems to work fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: On Windows, I have tried compiling with `pdftex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` but also with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` but I don't experienced your problem viewing the resulting PDF in SumatraPDF.

Comment: This should be fixed in the next version see https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/1505

Comment: @F.Pantigny: I've been compiling with overleaf and opening on windows, perhaps building on not-windows causes issues when opened on windows.